# мультиязычность в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я пишу бота для telegram на *Python* и хочу сделать его мультиязычным. Везде, где спрашивают про библиотеки для локализации, предлагают [*gettext*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html), но он тут не подходит, т.к. нужно в один момент получать сообщения на разных языках. Пока использую [*configparser*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), но мне кажется, что это костыль.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Использование gettext абсолютно никак не мешает условию «нужно в один момент получать сообщения на разных языках»

Comment: если я правильно понимаю все *gettext методы выбирают язык основываясь на глобальном языке, в то время как мне нужно вызывая метод типа gettext() явно задать язык - `gettext('some text', 'ru_RU')`, чего я не понимаю, что я проглядел, @andreymal ?

Comment: Язык выбирать точно можно. Но наизусть не помню как, попозже напишу

Comment: Так что, @andreymal ?

Comment: `gettext.translation(domain, каталог_с_языками, ['язык'])` позволяет получить нужный язык, об этом на первых страницах документации написано в общем-то

Comment: Хм, действительно не заметил. А из-за этого не будет проблем с генерацией .pot файла, @andreymal ?

Comment: С .pot файлом это никак не связано